# Class diagram interface with classes not adding any new methods

Tags: interface, uml, class-diagram

I'm in the process of creating a hangman game for Android, but I'm unsure about some parts of the class diagram. I have an Alphabet Interface With Methods for resetting, check if a letter is guessed, and marking it as guessed if it is not previously guessed.

The app will support both the Norwegian and English alphabet which means the the implementation of Methods will differ some.

In the class diagram, is it fine to leave the classes implementing the Interface empty or should I never do it this way unless they add New functionality?

[image]

being part of

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking your class diagram should contain as much detail as is needed to get the full picture without including every little detail. Someone unfamiliar with your project should be able to take it and implement it without asking too many questions.

If you have classes who's only purpose is to be a union of interfaces, those should be included in the diagram if they should be instantiated, even if they are empty. But generally they would not be empty..they would at least have a few members to keep track of things.

Comment: Given that these two classes will only have different implementations of the same Methods (their only purpose is to keep track of which letters are used in the given Language), would I be fine leaving the diagram linked as it is?

edit: would you mind taking a look at the Whole diagram and give a short review of it?

Comment: Your diagram is just fine as it is.

Comment: well...I think it is lacking a few methods like..check(useful for checking if a letter is actually part of the word). Alphabet is maybe not the best chosen name as it is not a representation of an alphabet, rather it represents the solution to the hangman game...But generally minor problems...

Comment: this Object is only for keeping track of the letters that has been guessed. I've got another Object for the Words used in the game.

I've added the Complete diagram for Reference

Comment: Your composition lines are the wrong way around.  The diamond should be on the container class, not the leaves/items.